# Second order, constant coefficient, differential equation probelm

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have this problem:

$$y''-6y'+9=0$$

the roots come out equal (3,3) thus the general solution is:

$$y= c_1e^{3t} +c_2te^{3t}$$

the initial values are :

$$y(0)=2$$
$$y'(0)=8$$

I tried solving this but my answers came out to be:
$$c_1=2$$
$$c_2=2$$

the actual answer is:

$$y(t) = 3e^{3t} − te^{3t}$$

How does$c_1$ come out to 3? If you plug in the values for $y(0)=2$

$$c_1e^{0}+c_2(0)e^{0}$$ $c_1$ comes out as 2...

So I don't know where my error. I have done it twice but it doesn't come out to that...

Any help?

Comment: the $y= c_1e^{3t} +c_2te^{3t}$ should be $y= c_1e^{-3t} +c_2te^{-3t}$

Comment: sorry I wrote the original equation wrong. I have edited it .

Comment: Your solution is correct and there may be a typo in the book.

Comment: your **correct answer** i.e. $y(t)=3e^{3t}-te^{3t}$, even dont follow the initial values because using this equation the answer of $y(0)$ is come out be $3$ not $2$.

Comment: ok. that helps. It makes more sense...thx